# Swift hide/show UIView in cell (data from database)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have UITableViewCell with UITextView and `UIView`

I'm try to hide/show `UIView`

[image]

Constraints — TextView:

> Trailing to Superview Equals 2
>
> Leading to Superview Equals 2
>
> Top to Superview Equals 2
>
> Bottom to Superview Equals 40

UIVIew:

> Trailing to Superview
>
> Leading to Superview
>
> Bottom to Superview
>
> Height 35

In Cell class I'm connect TextView BottomConstraint

UITableViewCell class :

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
 @IBOutlet weak var detailView: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var TextViewConstraintToBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        detailView.isHidden = true
        if detailView.isHidden == true {
            TextViewConstraintToBottom.constant = 0
        } else {
            TextViewConstraintToBottom.constant = 40

        }
}
```

In ViewController with UITableView :

```
    var handle: DatabaseHandle?
    var ref: DatabaseReference?

    var quoteList: [String] = []
    var songArray: [String] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self

        dataCatch()
}


func dataCatch() {

 ref = Database.database().reference()

        handle = ref?.child("Цитаты").child("\(cat)").child("\(quoteNAme)").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let username = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        
        if let us = username?["name"] {
                 self.quoteList.append(us as! String)
                 self.quoteList = self.quoteList.filter(){$0 != "1"}
                 self.myTableView.reloadData()
                 }

        if let us = username?["song"].unsafelyUnwrapped  {
                 self.celT?.detailView.isHidden = false
                 self.songArray.append(us as! String)
                 self.myTableView.reloadData()
                 }
                 })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! QuoteTableVC

let indexP = indexPath.row
cell.myTextView.text = quoteList[indexP]
cell.detailLabel.text = songArray[indexP]

return cell
}
```

In database I have structure
[image]

I decided

In ViewController :

```
func dataCatch() {

 ref = Database.database().reference()

        handle = ref?.child("Цитаты").child("\(cat)").child("\(quoteNAme)").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let username = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        if let us = username?["name"] {
                 self.quoteList.append(us as! String)
                 self.quoteList = self.quoteList.filter(){$0 != "1"}
                 self.myTableView.reloadData()
                 }

            if snapshot.hasChild("song") {
                let us = username?["song"]
                self.songArray.append(us as! String)

            } else {
                let tet = "1"
//                self.celT?.detailView.isHidden = true

                self.songArray.append(tet as! String)
            }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

cell.detailLabel.text = songArray[indexP]
        if cell.detailLabel.text != "1" {
            cell.detailView.isHidden = false
            cell.butConstraint.constant = 40
        } else {
            cell.detailView.isHidden = true
            cell.butConstraint.constant = 0
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `cellForRow`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UI TableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! QuoteTableVC

  // hide = check your model whether it has song or not

   if hide {
     cell.TextViewConstraintToBottom.constant = 0
  }
   else {
     cell.TextViewConstraintToBottom.constant = 40
   }

}
```